# How does modulus work exactly?

Tags: math, division, modulo

I know what modulus (%) does, it gives you the remainder. But how does it do that?
I saw that it uses the formula: modulus = dividend - (dividend / divisor) * divisor
10%3 should give you 1 (10 being the dividend and 3 being the divisor)
the forumla gives: 10-(10/3)*3 = 10-10 = 0 which is obviously wrong.

Then again, working with pure variables, dividend - ( dividend / divisor ) * divisor = dividend - dividend = 0

What am I doing wrong here?
(Also, the formula is from a native from JASS, the language used in warcraft 3 games)

Comment: see also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755946/what-is-the-purpose-of-negative-modulus-operator-results/6756109#6756109)

Comment: You forgot that `(10/3)` truncates toward `0`.  The result of this is `3`, not `3.3333333`...  So: `10-(10/3)*3 = 10-(3)*3 = 10-9 = 1`

Answer (score 4):

in the formula `(dividend / divisor)` is an integer division evaluating to an integer.

So, 10-(10/3)*3 = 10 - 9 = 1

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ^^ It was getting frustrating because no matter how many times I put it into the calculator, it gave me 0 xD

Answer (score 2):

In many programming languages using C, C++, Java, etc. 10/3 would result in 3 because divisions are actually integer-divisions and the fractional part is truncated.

So, in other words n/d gives you only the quotient.

Now, from arithmetic we know that any positive integer n and any positive integer divider d, n can be represented as: n = q*d + r. If 0 ≤ r < n (and it can be proven that there is only one such positive r that is less than n), q is called the quotient and r is the called the remainder.

In these programming languages, n/d gives you q.

So, n - (n/d)*d = n - q*d = r, the remainder.